# Wrong reception of data with UDP socket (C++)

Tags: c++, sockets, udp

Good morning,

I need to establish a UDP connection in order to send some data from a client to a server. I implemented the connection starting form this [example](http://linux.m2osw.com/c-implementation-udp-clientserver)  .

Then I defined my client.cc class:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "udp_client_server.h"
#include "prova.h"

using udp_client_server::udp_client;

#define LDM_IP "127.0.0.1"
#define LDM_PORT 5445       //8000

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "!!!I'm a client!!!" << endl; 

    prova *ciao = new prova() ;
    ciao->a = 86;
    ciao->b = 8.1;
    ciao->c = 90;

    udp_client_server::udp_client *client = new udp_client(LDM_IP, LDM_PORT);

    int b = client->send((char *)ciao,strlen((char *)ciao));

    if (b != strlen((char *)ciao)){
        std::cout<<"Packet corrupted "<< std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Then the sender.cc class :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

#include "udp_client_server.h"
#include "prova.h"

using udp_client_server::udp_server;

#define LDM_IP "127.0.0.1"
#define LDM_PORT 5445       //8000

using namespace std;

int main() {
    cout << "!!!I'm a server!!!" << endl;

    int size_max = 256; 

    udp_client_server::udp_server *server = new udp_server(LDM_IP, LDM_PORT);

    char *buffer;
    int gotMsg = server->recv(buffer,size_max);
    prova *pippo = new prova();
    pippo = (prova *)(buffer);

    std::cout<< "result " << gotMsg <<std::endl;
    std::cout<< "value " << pippo <<std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

The connection is establish, but I don't get the what I send. At each run I get a different wrong value instead of the transmitted one.

Could any one tell me where is the error?
Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no such thing as a UDP connection.

Comment: @EJP what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

send(.....,strlen((char *)ciao) 
doesnt send class

change your code,
send struct variable.

try
send(.....sizeof(prova));